# NOR circuit with two switches

Tags: logic-gates

I need to make a circuit that results in a 0(off) when one or both switches are closed. I am pretty sure this is a [NOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate) circuit, but I am confused on how to make it assert a 0 when the switch(es) are pressed.

Comment: What are the switches connected to (0V or +V) and do you want pull-ups or pull-downs on the input lines to force a known state when the switch is (normally) open (or normally closed)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the simplest *active* circuits is simply a single transistor and a couple of resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxuNm6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

R2 keeps the gate of Q1 low, so Q1 is naturally off.  That means that OUT is at the same potential as VDD less any voltage drop caused by the current draw through R1 depending on the load on OUT.  When either of SW1 or SW2, or both of them, are closed then the gate of Q1 rises above its threshold and turns on.  This drops the voltage of OUT to around 0V as the on resistance of Q1 is (or certainly should be) much lower than that of R1.

It is possible to do it even more simply without the transistor and just one resistor with a purely *passive* design:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbH7Mn.png)</sup>

When both switches are open the OUT voltage is held at (or near) VDD through the resistor.  When either switch is closed the OUT is connected direct to ground, so registers 0V.

You could also split that circuit into two separate ones and join them with a logic gate.  For instance, using an AND gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDRDpI.png)</sup>

Or, if you invert the switch logic so it gives a HIGH when closed you can use a NOR gate:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftICBZ.png)</sup>

Comment: Since the switches are beautiful lightning rods for dissipating the electrostatic charge from your body, I would add a series resistor between them and the gate, and an ESD protection diode between the sensitive gate of the mosfet and the ground. Alternatively, just use a small-signal NPN transistor - at the low currents involved, it will have a low V_CE.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, you are correct in your statement that this circuit is a NOR gate (neither one input, NOR the other) - the truth table for the nor gate is as follows:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{A} & \text{B} & Q \\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

(You already knew this)

Very quickly, if you just want a NOR gate in a circuit you can stop right here and go and buy a 7402 chip which has 4 two input NOR gates for your disposal - lovely.

However, if you want/need to make one then you need to take a look at how logic gates are constructed. Its done using electronic switches, for this we can use transistors - these have an input called the *Base*. Applying a logic 1 to the base simply throws the switch and creates a zero (or very close to) resistance path from the collector to the emitter. We can use this effect to make logic gates.

First, consider the humble NOT gate. If you put logic 1 in, you get logic zero out. you do this using a single transistor and a *pull up* resistor:

[image: NOT Gate]

In the not gate, when the base receives a low voltage the emitter and collector are not connected, meaning the collector pin (the output in this case) is held at 5V (logic 1). When the base receives a high voltage the transistor switches on, connecting the emitter and collector through an effectively zero resistance path, this means that the collector is connected to ground (logic zero). If you want to know what happened to the voltage, it is now all dropped across the 5K resistor.

So, that's a not gate, and now you should have a good idea how a logic gate can be made from a transistor (or any electronic switch, such as a relay.)

Now the NOR gate:

[image: NOR Gate]

Now there are two transistors- with collectors and emitters wired to the same point - each base providing an input. Switching either base ON (logic 1) will connect both collectors to ground. However if both bases are switched off then no current can flow and both collectors sit at 5V (logic 1).

Answer (score -2):

For the simplest case you can mislabel both switches so they are open when on and wire them in series.